# NodeJS Google Calendar API returns 'Missing scope type' error

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

When I make this call using the google api for nodejs:

```
var google   = require('googleapis');
var calendar = google.calendar('v3');  

calendar.acl.insert({
  calendarId : "exampleCalID@gmail.com",
  auth: auth.client,
  role: "reader",
  scope: {
    type: "user",
    value: "exampleUser@gmail.com"
  }
}, function(err, response){
  if(err)
    console.log(err)
  console.log(response);
  return;
});
```

I get the following error from the google API:

```
{ [Error: Missing scope type.]
code: 400,
errors: 
 [ { domain: 'global',
     reason: 'required',
     message: 'Missing scope type.' } ] }
```

Comment: Usually, this error happens when you are sending in an [invalid scope type](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-javascript-client/X5Zl4j35xNk). Please double check your request body if you are correctly specifying only [possible scope type](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert).

Comment: Yes,  that's what I thought at first.  But my scope type is "user"  which should be valid.  My only other thought is my request is structured wrong. Like my scope shouldn't be in the parameters,  but maybe somewhere else? Or the format of my parameters is missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. The role and scope data of this call need to be in an object called resource. [Line 128 of the source code](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/apis/calendar/v3.ts) makes this more clear than [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert), which is not language specific. So the function call should look like this:

```
var google   = require('googleapis');
var calendar = google.calendar('v3');  

calendar.acl.insert({
  calendarId : "exampleCalID@gmail.com",
  auth: auth.client,
  resource:{
    role: "reader",
    scope: {
      type: "user",
      value: "exampleUser@gmail.com"
    }
  }
}, function(err, response){
  if(err)
    console.log(err)
  console.log(response);
  return;
});
```